# Display message when amCharts renders a chart onto screen

Tags: r, shiny, amcharts

I am wondering what is the correct way to **display a Status message while `amCharts` plots chart on the screen**. I am using `amCharts` in my Shiny app with the package `rAmCharts`, and my plot consists of huge number of data. In local server chart is plotted quite quickly, however, when I deploy my app onto `AWS`, rendering chart takes a considerable amount of time. I, therefore, plan to display some message to let the user know something is happening.

Below is the code of my App :

```
library(shiny)
library(rAmCharts) 
library(shinyjs)


 ui = fluidPage(
    inlineCSS(" #curtain {
                  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
                  color: #fff;
                  font-size: 25px;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 1%;
                  width: 50%;
                  text-align: center;
                  z-index: 1000;
                }"),

    amChartsOutput("amPLot", height = "485px"),                                     
    useShinyjs(),
    div(id = "curtain")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
     PDF = density(rnorm(1000000))
     Dat = data.frame(x = PDF$x, y = PDF$y)

     Plot = amXYChart(x = Dat$x, y = Dat$y) %>%
            setDataProvider(dataProvider = Dat, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
            addGraph(xField = "x", yField = "y", lineColor = "#058e54", fillAlphas = 0.5, bullet = "round", lineThickness = 1, bulletColor = "transparent")
    Plot@listeners = list(event = 'rendered', method = JS("function(e) {
                                                              document.getElementById('curtain').innerHTML='Displaying plot';
                                                            }"))

    output$amPLot = renderAmCharts(Plot)
    hide(id = "curtain", anim = TRUE, animType = "fade")   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However code doesnt seem to be working as intended, as I failed to see any message while chart is beling plotted onto screen.

I would appreciate if someone guide me through the right approach.

**Based on the Feedback received from `jspcal`, below is my modified code - however still no success**

```
library(shiny)
library(rAmCharts) 
require(purrr)
library(htmlwidgets)


 ui = fluidPage(
    inlineCSS(" #curtain {
                  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
                  color: #fff;
                  font-size: 25px;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 1%;
                  width: 50%;
                  text-align: center;
                  z-index: 1000;
                }"),

    div(id="chart-container", 
        div(id="chart-div"),
        div(id="curtain", "Chart is loading...")),

    amChartsOutput("amPLot", height = "485px")                              

)

server = function(input, output, session) {
     PDF = density(rnorm(1000000))
     Dat = data.frame(x = PDF$x, y = PDF$y)

     Plot = amXYChart(x = Dat$x, y = Dat$y) %>%
            setDataProvider(dataProvider = Dat, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
            addGraph(xField = "x", yField = "y", lineColor = "#058e54", fillAlphas = 0.5, bullet = "round", lineThickness = 1, bulletColor = "transparent")
    Plot@listeners = list(event = 'rendered', method = JS("function(e) {
                                                              document.getElementById('curtain').style.display = 'none';
                                                            }"))    

    output$amPLot = renderAmCharts(Plot)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you see, while the `div = curtain` is displayed from the initialization of the chart, it is not going off after the chart is displayed fully. Any further help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The rendered event fires when the chart is fully displayed. In the initial state, the page can display a loading message. When the event handler is called, the message can be updated or hidden within the handler code. It seems in the code snippet above the div is hidden immediately instead of waiting for the event handler to be called.

From the example at https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/displaying-loading-indicator-chart-loaded/

```
<div id="chart-container">
    <div id="chart-div"></div>
    <div id="curtain">Chart is loading...</div>
</div>
```

The message is shown in the initial markup before anything happens. In your code, make sure the page has this message initially. When the handler is called the message div is removed.

Comment: Hi jspcal, thanks for your pointer. However can you please be a bit explicit how can I make my page to display a loading message in the initial state?

Comment: Sure take a look at [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/displaying-loading-indicator-chart-loaded/)

Comment: I know that link, my R implementation was actually taken from that link only - but unfortunately mine one is not working

Comment: In the example, the message is shown in a div within the initial markup. The message is hidden after the handler is called.

Comment: Hi  jspcal, I have updated my code based on your feedback. I now display message at the initialization of the chart, however, fail to take that off post chart is displayed on the screen. Any further suggestion why it is not going away?

Comment: Try to see if your rendered callback is being executed (using debugger, or show an alert in the callback).

Comment: Change the method to just display Alert : JS("function(e) {
                                                              alert('Completed');                                                        }") - even that is not displayed

Comment: I wonder if that example code works in your environment. Might want to look at the source too to see if your events are getting registered.

Comment: I checked running raw HTML code with CSS and JS as in the original link. It is working fine, but not my R implementation